# Drawing brackets on the side of the circuit

Tags: qcircuit

I need some help with drawing the brackets around the circuit. The result of the code below is presented in the first image. I want to draw brackets around the circuit and write the letter p on top of it. Basically, I want the same image as the second one, except with the VQE circuit. I would really appreciate it if someone can help me with this.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{report}

\usepackage{qcircuit}
\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{equation*}
      \Qcircuit @C=0.5em @R=1em {
            \lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{R_Y(\theta_1)} &\gate{R_Z(\theta_5)} &\qw &\qw &\ctrl{1} &\qw       &\qw      &\qw   &\qw  &\gate{R_Y(\theta_9)}    &\gate{R_Z(\theta_{13})} &\qw\\
            \lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{R_Y(\theta_2)} &\gate{R_Z(\theta_6)} &\qw &\qw &\targ    &\ctrl{1}  &\qw      &\qw   &\qw  &\gate{R_Y(\theta_{10})} &\gate{R_Z(\theta_{14})} &\qw\\
            \lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{R_Y(\theta_3)} &\gate{R_Z(\theta_7)} &\qw &\qw &\qw      &\targ     &\ctrl{1} &\qw   &\qw  &\gate{R_Y(\theta_{11})} &\gate{R_Z(\theta_{15})} &\qw\\
            \lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{R_Y(\theta_4)} &\gate{R_Z(\theta_8)} &\qw &\qw &\qw      &\qw       &\targ    &\qw   &\qw  &\gate{R_Y(\theta_{12})} &\gate{R_Z(\theta_{16})} &\qw }
    \end{equation*}  
  \caption{VQE circuit}
  \label{img-vqe-circuit}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never use the package qcircuit, but in the doc

1. the option braket: \usepackage[braket]{qcircuit}
2. no equation* but [ and ]
3. \gategroup{1}{1}{4}{12}{.7em}{{} for th bracket
4. \ustick{p} in line 1

   ```
   \documentclass[landscape]{report}

   \usepackage[braket]{qcircuit}
   \begin{document}

   \begin{figure}[h]
       %\begin{equation*}
       \[\Qcircuit @C=0.5em @R=1em {
       \lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{R_Y(\theta_1)} &\gate{R_Z(\theta_5)} &\qw &\qw &\ctrl{1} &\qw&\qw      &\qw&\qw&\gate{R_Y(\theta_9)}&\gate{R_Z(\theta_{13})} &\qw&\ustick{p}\\
           \lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{R_Y(\theta_2)} &\gate{R_Z(\theta_6)} &\qw &\qw &\targ    &\ctrl{1}  &\qw      &\qw   &\qw  &\gate{R_Y(\theta_{10})} &\gate{R_Z(\theta_{14})} &\qw\\
           \lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{R_Y(\theta_3)} &\gate{R_Z(\theta_7)} &\qw &\qw &\qw      &\targ     &\ctrl{1} &\qw   &\qw  &\gate{R_Y(\theta_{11})} &\gate{R_Z(\theta_{15})} &\qw\\
           \lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{R_Y(\theta_4)} &\gate{R_Z(\theta_8)} &\qw &\qw &\qw      &\qw       &\targ    &\qw   &\qw  &\gate{R_Y(\theta_{12})} &\gate{R_Z(\theta_{16})} &\qw
           \gategroup{1}{1}{4}{12}{.7em}{\{}
           \gategroup{1}{1}{4}{12}{.7em}{\}}
           }
       \]
       %\end{equation*}  
       \caption{VQE circuit}
       \label{img-vqe-circuit}
   \end{figure}
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]